# Fine resolution delays

Tags: ruby, arm, delay, sleep

Is there a better method than `sleep` in Ruby to implement fine/high resolution delays?

I am wanting to implement the DHT11 sensor protocol in pure ruby and I can not get consistent delays with the native `sleep` method.

The delays in question are as high as 20 milliseconds down to 40 microseconds.

To test these delays I am running a simple delta time calculation as follows:

```
irb(main):043:0> # 20ms delays are fine
irb(main):044:0* 5.times do
irb(main):045:1*   t1 = Time.now.to_f
irb(main):046:1>   sleep 0.02
irb(main):047:1>   t2 = Time.now.to_f
irb(main):048:1>   puts t2 - t1
irb(main):049:1> end
0.02004218101501465
0.021020889282226562
0.020302772521972656
0.020184040069580078
0.020570993423461914

irb(main):050:0> # 40us delays are inconsistant and/or broken
irb(main):051:0* 5.times do
irb(main):052:1*   t1 = Time.now.to_f
irb(main):053:1>   sleep 0.00004
irb(main):054:1>   t2 = Time.now.to_f
irb(main):055:1>   puts t2 - t1
irb(main):056:1> end
0.0
0.0
0.0005059242248535156
0.0
0.0
```

Is this protocol which depends on microsecond delays possible to implement in Ruby?

The build being tested on is `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [i386-mingw32]` and was running on `Windows 10`. Although when running the same tests on an H2 CPU with `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [arm-linux-gnueabihf]`
 on `Linux orangepizero 4.13.16-sunxi #20 SMP Fri Nov 24 19:50:07 CET 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux` on the development board I am going to be using the sensors with I get some finer resolution outcomes but the result is still inconsistent:

```
irb(main):001:0> # 20ms delays are fine
irb(main):002:0* 5.times do
irb(main):003:1*   t1 = Time.now.to_f
irb(main):004:1>   sleep 0.02
irb(main):005:1>   t2 = Time.now.to_f
irb(main):006:1>   puts t2 - t1
irb(main):007:1> end
0.020125150680541992
0.020093679428100586
0.020082950592041016
0.020090341567993164
0.020081043243408203


irb(main):008:0> # 40us delays are inconsistant and/or broken
irb(main):009:0* 5.times do
irb(main):010:1*   t1 = Time.now.to_f
irb(main):011:1>   sleep 0.00004
irb(main):012:1>   t2 = Time.now.to_f
irb(main):013:1>   puts t2 - t1
irb(main):014:1> end
0.0003037452697753906
0.00022101402282714844
0.00022673606872558594
0.0002200603485107422
0.00021409988403320312
```

Will this ever be possible or am I looking to have to write or use someone else C implementation and then call it from Ruby?

Comment: I suspect the problem is more that you're running a multitasking OS, and as such have no way to choose how long a sleep is over a minimum amount of time. Whether a C implementation will behave any differently is down to the OS. This type of task, where timing is critical is best handled by a bare metal, or RTOS programmed microcontroller, rather than a general purpose machine running a full fledged OS. I would handle it with a cheap micro (cortex M0, or a tiny PIC), have that talk to the DHT11, and communicate with your orange pi via a serial link.

Comment: @Colin__s thanks for the reply. I will look into that option. I asked this question because there are C libraries and even a ruby gem based off a C library (https://github.com/chetan/dht-sensor-ffi) that are able to interpret the sensor. I was just curious if I could achieve the same resolution timings as C to implement the protocol in pure ruby.